# What is wrong with this MySQL query. It gives invalid parameter number error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

MySQL gives this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number
```

for this query:

```
public function getUserFriends($userId) {
    $query = "SELECT users.id, users.firstName, users.lastName, users.thumbPic FROM friendships LEFT JOIN users ON ((friendships.user1 = users.id OR friendships.user2 = users.id) AND users.id <> :userId) WHERE (user1 = :userId OR user2 = :userId) AND friendships.status = 1";
    return $this->adapter->prepare($query)->execute(array(':userId' => $userId))->fetchAll();
}
```

Parameter number looks ok to me or am I missing something?

Comment: You cannot reuse the same placeholder `:userId` multiple times in the query, unfortunately.

Comment: You use :userId 3 times.

Comment: _You cannot use a named parameter marker of the same name twice in a prepared statement_ http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski that's weird; is that new?  I've never had a problem doing that, and evodevo's code actually runs fine for me

Comment: @ExplosionPills Don't know - I don't think I've ever tested it, but it has been the issue on a number of PDO questions I'ves seen here... The implementation doesn't really make sense.

Comment: In most other database drivers, the whole idea of named placeholders is to re-use them. How annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't use the same named parameter twice. You have to accomplish your goal this way: (I know... lame, right?)

```
public function getUserFriends($userId) {
    $query = "
        SELECT
            users.id, users.firstName, users.lastName, users.thumbPic 
        FROM
            friendships 
        LEFT JOIN 
            users ON 
                (friendships.user1 = users.id OR friendships.user2 = users.id) 
                AND users.id <> :userIdA
        WHERE 
            (user1 = :userIdB OR user2 = :userIdC) 
            AND friendships.status = 1";
    return $this->adapter->prepare($query)->execute(array(
        ':userIdA' => $userId
        ':userIdB' => $userId
        ':userIdC' => $userId
    ))->fetchAll();
}
```